# Symfony2 Form works bad(Related oneToMany entities are not deleted)

Tags: symfony, doctrine, one-to-many, formbuilder, symfony-2.8

I have an `Article` and the `Tags` entities.
I want to create form to edit `Article` and related `Tags`. *(There also exist a lot of another relation but for now this is not important)*
In my case adding new tags works great. But if i want delete some tag, or edit existing, this not happen and i'm not getting an error. As i know `$em->flush()` should resolve this all but it's not.
Also I have checked my engine - It's InnoDB. I have already created Foreign Keys.

For editing tages i'm using `TextType::class`. So if i want to remove one of tag i should remove it from this list.
[click to see tag input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrfDX.png)

Form element

```
$builder->add($builder->create('custom_tags', TextType::class, [])->addModelTransformer(function(){/*to array*/}, function(){/*to string*/} );
```

I Tied up this entities as documentation says:

**Article Entity:**

```
 /**
   * Article entity
   *
   * @ORM\Table(name="Article")
   * @ORM\Entity
   */
   class Article
   {
       /**
        * Article can have zero or more tags
        *
        * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="article",
        *     cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
        */
        private $tags;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        public function setTags($tags) {
            $currTags = $this->getTags();
            ....
            // calculating the difference between currTags and ModifiedTags
            //here I got ArrayCollection with new tags entities list, without already deleted tags
            $this->tags = $tags;
            return $this;
        }

        public function getTags() {
             return $this->tags->matching(Criteria::create()->orderBy(["id" => Criteria::DESC]);
        }
        ...
```

**Tag Entity**

```
/**
 * Tag
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Tag")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class Tag
 {
 /**
  * @var Article
  *
  * Many Tags can be present in one article.
  *
  * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="tags")
  * @JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
  private $article;

  ...
```

I spent a lot of time to find information and to resolve this issue...
Could anyone give some advice, show me what i have missed or give some links? Should i realize remove_action manually or specify this action explicitly? Thanks!

Comment: Have you added `setArticle($article)` function in `Tag` entity?

Comment: Maybe you should use "on cascade delete" in your doctrine configuration file.

Comment: @Mintho433, What do you mean ? Where i should configure it ?
I did not say but when I edit article field in my form, tags records are remove from table...

Comment: @DrKey , yes I used it.

Comment: Can anyone explain me
If i have arrayCollection of entites. And I remove one of entities and then I call flush function. Will appropriate row in table be deleted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that getTags() function returns ArrayCollection. 
And this is fine. But I'm also calling getTags() in setTags() to calculate the difference between currTags and ModifiedTags. 
So I was making changes in ArrayCollection instance.
But when I became use $this->tags

> Once an ArrayCollection is persisted and managed by the entity manager
>   it becomes a PersistentCollection it behaves exactly has an
>   ArrayCollection
>   [(got from here???)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687153/doctrine-why-i-get-persistentcollection-and-an-empty-array-on-manytomany?answertab=active#tab-top)

which instance of Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection instead $this->getTags() in Article class - all started work well. 
So Now I need to read about difference between Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection and ArrayCollection